# AuthorizationHeaderMalformed Error when upload a file on S3 using Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-sdk-js

I had this part of code to send a file to S3 using Amplify

```
     const file = e.target.files[0];
            try {
                console.log(Storage.vault)
                await Storage.put(file.name, file);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log('Error uploading file: ', error);
            }
```

But always return this error:

```
<Error>
<Code>AuthorizationHeaderMalformed</Code>
<Message>The authorization header is malformed; the authorization header requires three components: Credential, SignedHeaders, and Signature.</Message>
<RequestId>YP2HEHPE20T13HNJ</RequestId>
<HostId>T5mH0m+CHZ6n/JuShi7FdUBYZt3BEz4QiEHMmckL0v5VrB7DqupGbmadxDgZnitWFI0IUYVmBig=</HostId></Error>
```

I using Cognito to make login to my system, and use this code to setting de configuration of Amplify

```
   Auth: {
        identityPoolId: process.env.REACT_APP_IDENTITY_POOL_ID, 
        region: process.env.REACT_APP_REGION,
        userPoolId: process.env.REACT_APP_USER_POOL_ID,
        userPoolWebClientId: process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_ID,
    },
    Storage: {
        AWSS3: {
            region: process.env.REACT_APP_REGION,
            bucket: process.env.REACT_APP_BUCKET,
        }
    }
```

If i use the AWS SDK getting connection info on Amplify, i can make the upload on S3, but only with Amplify don't.

To configure my Bucket and Identity pool i used the amplify docs.

Comment: I'm getting the exact same issue. Did the same set up, and Amplify was working fine for months. Now I get this error out of the blue.